# S3 method dispatch with S4 methods

Tags: r, r-s4, method-dispatch

I have some trouble understanding the differences in method dispatching between S3 and S4 classes. As far as I understand, S3 classes use `UseMethod` and finds the correct method via the `class` attribute of the object passed. S4 classes use `StandardGeneric` and work with function signatures (I'm reading [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s4)). But the following code runs:

```
myfun <- function(x, y = NULL) {
  UseMethod("myfun")
}

myfun.default <- function(x, y) {
  print("default method")
}

myfun.integer <- function(x, y) {
  print("S3 dispatch for integer")
}

setMethod("myfun",
          signature = c(x = "matrix", y = "ANY"),
          function(x, y) {
            print("S4 dispatch for matrices")
          }
)

setMethod("myfun",
          signature = c(x = "character", y = "ANY"),
          function(x, y) {
            print("S4 dispatch for strings")
          }
)

setMethod("myfun",
          signature = c(x = "character", y = "character"),
          function(x, y) {
            print("S4 dispatch for string + string")
          }
)

myfun(iris)
## [1] "default method"
myfun(1:10)
## [1] "S3 dispatch for integer"
myfun(matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
## [1] "S4 dispatch for matrices"
myfun("foo")
## [1] "S4 dispatch for strings"
myfun("foo", y = "bar")
## [1] "S4 dispatch for string + string"
```

What exactly is going on here? I created an S3 method called "myfun", for which the S3 method dispatch works as intended. So far, so good.

But this S3 method also correctly dispatches S4 methods, even though I didn't define a StandardGeneric for these S4 methods (or convert myfun to such). How come? Any background would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `myFun` became an S4 generic the first time you called `setMethod` (which can only create S4 methods for (S4) generic functions).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation